# node.js app works on localhost, but not after uploading to cpanel

Tags: node.js, cpanel

I've been trying to deploy a Node.js application on a shared hosting account via cPanel. The application works locally, but after deployment, while the static pages load correctly, I encounter a persistent 404 error when trying to access specific routes (`/wishes`) responsible for fetching JSON data using `fetch()` in my client-side JavaScript (`script.js`). I've ensured that the server-side routes are correctly defined in `server.js` and that the base URI and routing configurations in my `.htaccess` file are set up properly.

**Attempts made:**

- Verified the correct path and base URI in fetch requests (`fetch('/wishes')`)
- Checked server logs (`stderr.log`), but found no useful error information
- Verified and adjusted server-side route definitions in `server.js`
- Implemented additional error logging to track potential issues in server-side route handling
- Ensured correct server configurations and URI settings in the `.htaccess` file

Despite these attempts, the 404 error persists. I've spent a considerable amount of time troubleshooting and researching, yet haven't found a resolution. As a temporary solution, I re-implemented the backend logic in PHP and now my app runs fine, but I still wan't to know what went wrong, so maybe next time I can try node.js again. So I'd greatly appreciate any guidance or insights into why the specific routes (`/wishes`) in my Node.js app result in 404 errors post-deployment on a shared hosting server via cPanel. Any advice on potential server configuration issues, routing problems, or suggestions for further debugging steps would be immensely helpful. Thank you!

I really don't get why those routes work perfectly on localhost but not on my hosting.

---